# Corrupt Monitor Profile

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-photoshop, display-settings, color-profiles

When launching Photoshop I received the error "Your Monitor Profile appears to be corrupt. Please re-run your monitor calibration."   I assume this happened because I installed a new video card (went from NVIDIA to ATI). But I see no way to re-calibrate and reset the profile in my ATI settings. I have set my monitor to my liking and it seems to work fine.

How do I reset my monitor profile so Photoshop reads and uses the correct profile?

Note: If I use the "corrupted" profile the colors are indeed way off. But if I ignore it everything looks okay. But for consistency I would prefer to have a correct profile. Also I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I correct this error was I went into my Display Settings using my video card software (AMD Catalyst) and I was able to choose another profile. I choose sRGB profile which was similar to the original profile.

Answer (score 1):

Click Start > Settings > Control Panel > Adobe Gamma and choose Step by Step wizard. See if that helps.

Comment: Adobe Gamma doesn't ship with Photoshop anymore. (and hasn't for past several versions) http://forums.adobe.com/thread/604844

Comment: Aw that is unfortunate, good information Lynda.